# how to test scroll event handler in jest

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jestjs

I am calling `$('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').scroll()` method in my js file. But can't find out how to test this method using JEST.

Full code is below:

```
$('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').scroll(event => {
     let $width = $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').outerWidth();
     let $scrollWidth = $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row')[0].scrollWidth;
     let $scrollLeft = $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').scrollLeft();
     if ($scrollWidth - $width === $scrollLeft) {
        $('.all-products-tab-buttons').addClass('remove');
     } else {
        $('.all-products-tab-buttons').removeClass('remove');
     }
});
```

How may I test if and else conditions also?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

function main() {
  $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').scroll((event) => {
    let $width = $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').outerWidth();
    let $scrollWidth = $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row')[0].scrollWidth;
    let $scrollLeft = $('.all-products-tab-buttons .row').scrollLeft();
    if ($scrollWidth - $width === $scrollLeft) {
      $('.all-products-tab-buttons').addClass('remove');
    } else {
      $('.all-products-tab-buttons').removeClass('remove');
    }
  });
}

export default main;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import main from './';
import $ from 'jquery';

jest.mock('jquery', () => jest.fn());

describe('60003884', () => {
  it('should add class', () => {
    const tabButtonRows = [{ scrollWidth: 200 }];
    tabButtonRows.constructor.prototype.scroll = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((handler) => {
      handler();
    });
    tabButtonRows.constructor.prototype.outerWidth = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(100);
    tabButtonRows.constructor.prototype.scrollLeft = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(100);
    const tabButtons = { addClass: jest.fn(), removeClass: jest.fn() };

    $.mockImplementation((selector) => {
      switch (selector) {
        case '.all-products-tab-buttons .row':
          return tabButtonRows;
        case '.all-products-tab-buttons':
          return tabButtons;
      }
    });
    main();
    expect(tabButtons.addClass).toBeCalledWith('remove');
  });

  it('should remove class', () => {
    const tabButtonRows = [{ scrollWidth: 200 }];
    tabButtonRows.constructor.prototype.scroll = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((handler) => {
      handler();
    });
    tabButtonRows.constructor.prototype.outerWidth = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(100);
    tabButtonRows.constructor.prototype.scrollLeft = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(50);
    const tabButtons = { addClass: jest.fn(), removeClass: jest.fn() };

    $.mockImplementation((selector) => {
      switch (selector) {
        case '.all-products-tab-buttons .row':
          return tabButtonRows;
        case '.all-products-tab-buttons':
          return tabButtons;
      }
    });
    main();
    expect(tabButtons.removeClass).toBeCalledWith('remove');
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/60003884/index.test.js (14.309s)
  60003884
    ✓ should add class (7ms)
    ✓ should remove class (1ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        16.079s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/60003884